# Libgdx Game Crashes on 7th Restart Memory Error On Samsung Android Phone

Tags: android, libgdx

Hello I am creating a game on android using Libgdx.  I am currently testing my game on a Samsung Galaxy Ace samsung gts5830i mobile phone.  After reloading the game screen 7 times it crashes giving this error: rtos common memory zero linear buffer allocated, Big Mem out of handles.  I had the same problem when loading my shop screen and high score screen but I solved that by disposing everything and deleting duplicate objects i.e. 2 Spritebatch objects textures etc.

I have disposed of everything I can possibly think of in my main game screen, cleared the stage, nulled all references etc but the problem still persists.  There are 4-5 different sprite sheets 512*512 so I am pretty sure they aren't the problem.

I eventually set up eclipse mat after much error solving to find any memory leaks. However DDMS and the debugger rarely work and I am new to it so don't fully understand how to use it.  I managed to get a heap dump of my game crashing.  I think the problem may be with the Spritebatch and floats? Please see images.

[image: Dominator Tree]

[image: Spritebatchfloat problem?]

I have read on another forum that this error is common with low end Samsung devices and that hardware is the fault and it can't be fixed.  Yet it went away with my other screens and the amount of reloads increased from 3 to 7 before crashing?  If you have any pointers or tips it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could it possibly be because I am loading textures in another class i.e a weapons class and not disposing of them?

Comment: I believe this may have been the cause of the problem as the game now restarts fine on 20 goes (the most I've tried).  I completely forgot about those textures in them classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "7th reload"? What is being reloaded? Do you meant that after the 7th restarting of the game it crashes?

Comment: When I go into the menu and start the game - load the game screen.  When the game finishes I go back to the menu screen and then start the game again i.e restart or reload the game screen.  After playing the game 7 times it crashed.  I believe I found the problem - in my game I was loading a weapons texture in another class I forgot about each time I loaded the game screen a new instance was being created hence why memory was continually growing and it eventually ran out.  I disposed of the textures and it all works fine.